# Bootstrap "Tour" bug when I start it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-8, bootstrap-tour

I have a site built with `Drupal 8` and `Bootstrap 3`. When a user visited the site, `Tour` starts automatically. When `Tour` is finished, a cookie is placed in the browser of the visitor so that `Tour` will not start when the user reloads the page.

**The Site:**
https://www.s1biose.com

**My problem :**

I created a button on the left menu `Commencer la visite`, so that users access the `Tour` manually.

Every time I restart the `Tour` manually, a bug will appear from time to time. It must be restarted several times on a different page to see the bug.

How to correct this?

Here is the code I added at the end of my `bs-tour.js` file :

```
        // Restart the tour
        var startTour = $('#bs-tour-restart');
        startTour.click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var tourObject = drupalSettings.bs_tour.currentTour;
          if (tourObject && tourObject._options.steps.length) {
            tourObject.start(true);
          }
        });

        // Close collapse navigation
        $('#bs-tour-restart').click(function () {
        $('#navbar-collapse-first, #navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
        });
```

Here is my bs-tour.js file :

```
(function ($, _, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.bsTour = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(window).on('load', function (event) {
        try
        {
          var tourOptions = $(drupalSettings.bs_tour.tour)[0];
          var tips = tourOptions.steps;
          var keyboard = tourOptions.keyboard;
          var debug = tourOptions.debug;
          var steps = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < tips.length; i++) {
            if ($(tips[i].element).length > 0) {
              tips[i].backdropPadding.top = parseInt(tips[i].backdropPadding.top);
              tips[i].backdropPadding.right = parseInt(tips[i].backdropPadding.right);
              tips[i].backdropPadding.bottom = parseInt(tips[i].backdropPadding.bottom);
              tips[i].backdropPadding.left = parseInt(tips[i].backdropPadding.left);

              switch (tips[i].backdrop) {
                case "0":
                  tips[i].backdrop = false;
                  break;

                case "1":
                  tips[i].backdrop = true;
                  break;
              }

              steps.push(tips[i]);
            }
          }

          if (steps.length) {
            var tour = new Tour({
              debug: debug,
              keyboard: keyboard,
              template: "<div class='popover tour'>\
              <div class='arrow'></div>\
              <h3 class='popover-title'></h3>\
              <div class='popover-content'></div>\
              <div class='popover-navigation'>\
              <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« " + Drupal.t('Prev') + "</button>\
              <span data-role='separator'>|</span>\
              <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='next'>" + Drupal.t('Next') + " »</button>\
              <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='end'>" + Drupal.t('Skip tour') + "</button>\
              </div>\
              </div>",
            });

            // Add steps to the tour
            tour.addSteps(steps);

            // Initialize the tour
            tour.init();

            // Start the tour
            tour.start();

            // Restart the tour
            var startTour = $('#bs-tour-restart');
            startTour.click(function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              var tourObject = drupalSettings.bs_tour.currentTour;
              if (tourObject && tourObject._options.steps.length) {
                tourObject.start(true);
              }
            });

            // Close collapse navigation
            $('#bs-tour-restart').click(function () {
            $('#navbar-collapse-first, #navbar-collapse-second').collapse('hide');
            });

            // Add tour object to drupalSettings to allow manipulating tour from other modules.
            // Example: drupalSettings.bs_tour.currentTour.end();
            drupalSettings.bs_tour.currentTour = tour;
          }

        } catch (e) {
          // catch any fitvids errors
          window.console && console.warn('Bootstrap tour stopped with the following exception');
          window.console && console.error(e);
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(window.jQuery, window._, window.Drupal, window.drupalSettings);
```

When I start the `Tour`, the background is black :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but when I launched the visit, I thought that it finish in the 'menu right'.

I looked into your js and I've seen that there were other steps, exactly 8. 
One thing is that you should implement a scroll to function that target the opened step.

So I scrolled to bottom, and then I finish the tour when I see that the next button was grey, the tour is finish, and I can't reproduce your issue.

I think you should use the 'onShown' option (http://bootstraptour.com/api/) to make the window scroll to the targeted element.

Finally (I think) is that your issue is just caused because the tour is not finish ??

---

Maybe you can test with a code like this, It's not tested but it's something similar.

```
        var tour = new Tour({
          debug: debug,
          onShown: function(tour){
              var target = tour._options.steps[tour.getCurrentStep()].element;

                  $('html, body').animate({
                     scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
                   }, 2000);
          },
          keyboard: keyboard,
          template: "<div class='popover tour'>\
          <div class='arrow'></div>\
          <h3 class='popover-title'></h3>\
          <div class='popover-content'></div>\
          <div class='popover-navigation'>\
          <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« " + Drupal.t('Prev') + "</button>\
          <span data-role='separator'>|</span>\
          <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='next'>" + Drupal.t('Next') + " »</button>\
          <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='end'>" + Drupal.t('Skip tour') + "</button>\
          </div>\
          </div>",
        });
```

Comment: I updated the question. The new code fixes the problem. But I still have the problem of "Tour" which does not scroll the page automatically. Where to put 'onShown' in the code above ?